# how to use shell script (external command) to select a file to open&edit

Tags: external-command

I've got a shell script: `find... | stuff | xargs vi` which works fine from the shell. But if I invoke that from inside Vim like `:! find... | stuff | xargs vi` it's kinda weird... like maybe I'm seeing different instance of vim that's spawned in a new shell? In that new vim `:ls` only shows the new buffer and after doing `:q` (from this mystery vim instance) then `:ls` shows the previous buffers available.

So do I want to use `:e` for this? I was reading several posts about `:edit` and `:enew` and such, but couldn't figure out how to combine that with this shell pipeline.

---

edit:
vim seems to be struggling with the shell globbing? and is it not able to accept piped commands through this syntax?

```
:e `find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | shuf -n 1`
E79: Cannot expand wildcards
"`find . -type f -not -path '*/.*'" [New DIRECTORY]
E492: Not an editor command: shuf -n 1`
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

results in a buffer:

```
2 %a   "`find . -type f -not -path '*/.*'" line 1
```

Comment: What if you leave off the backslash on the `.` in `-path '*/\.*'`?

Comment: doesn't your comment show an extra backslash that code does *not* show?

Comment: I'm suggesting instead of `:args \`find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | shuf -n 1\`` you try `:args \`find . -type f -not -path '*/.*' | shuf -n 1\``, since I don't think that backslash is having any effect, but I could be wrong. It appears that the pipe was also part of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backquotes in an Ex command in Vim to use the output of a shell command as part of the Ex command arguments, similarly to how backquotes work on a Bourne shell.

Note that this seems to only work on Unix versions of Vim, not on Windows.

If you have a pipeline, you need to escape the pipes with a backslash and turn them into `\|`. The reason for that is that `|` is the command separator in Ex and Vim will first split the line into multiple Ex commands and then try to parse the backquotes, in which case an unescaped `|` will produce an unterminated backquoted shell command.

In your case, if your pipeline produces a single filename, you can use:

```
:e `find ... \| stuff`
```

If it produces more than one filename, then `:e` won't be able to take it (it only takes a single file), but in that case you can use `:args` to open all the files as "argument" files, which makes them work with `:n` to skip to the next file (exactly the same as passing filenames as arguments in the `vi` command-line.)

```
:args `find ... \| stuff`
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my pipeline. I just edited my question to include the errors.

Comment: @alec Indeed! My local test was too simple and used a single command. If you have a pipe, you need to escape it, using `\|`. It's possible that you also need to escape your backslash (turning it into two). Hopefully that will fix it. I updated the answer to explain why it needs to be quoted and updated the examples too.

Comment: are there other special characters that need to be escaped the way `|` does in this context of using backticks to provide shell output as argument to ex command?

Comment: @alec I think it's hard to tell, since Vimscript escaping rules can be quite arcane... I guess probably backslash needs to be escaped (into two backslashes) and you might be able to escape a backquote itself with backslash backquote (though it's quite probable that one won't work at all.) There's also shell rules going into effect here, so it's quite a layered cake at that point... In any case, I imagine this was close to what you wanted, so hopefully it's useful. If you need more control, look into `system()` or `systemlist()` functions, that's more verbose but it can be better on escaping.

Comment: haha ""Vimscript escaping rules can be quite arcane"" exactly... that's why i asked :)
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new command as such:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Find arglocal `=system("/usr/bin/find "..<q-args>)`
```

As the command does **not** have `:h :command-bar` attribute, the whole argument is passed to shell and the following works as expected:

```
:Find ... | stuff
```

All found files get into the local arglist and you can do as usual `:next`, `:prev` etc.

This also works in Windows provided that you have MSYS/bash and all the coretools installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since in windows you can't just :e `find ... \| stuff` , you need something cleverer. And if you don't have cygwin, it is mostly prefered to use wsl.

```
func! AddFiles(grep)
   redir => tmp
   call RunPS('RunBash "' . a:grep . '"')
   redir END
   for l in split(tmp,'\n')
       if filereadable(l) 
           exec ':e '.l
        endif
    endfor
endfunc
func! RunPS(var)
        exec 'silent! !Import-Module ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1;' . a:var
endfunction
```

RunBash is a powershell function that looks like this

```
function RunBash($fil)
{
wsl bash -c "source ~/.bash_profile; $fil" 
}
```

Sorry for the Blasphemy :)

For example,

```
    call AddFiles("find . -iname '*.py' | grep -v __init__")
```

Comment: It could be improved using Matt method maybe..